# Arranging people in two circles

Tags: combinatorics

> There are $12$ kids in a birthday party, they play a game where they sit in two circles, the bigger one is created by $7$ kids, and the smaller one by $5$ kids. How many ways can the kids be arranged?

Here is what I did:

$$n= (7-1)!\cdot (5-1)!== 6!\cdot 4!$$

I'm not sure I'm right, so I would like to verify my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is incorrect.  This would be correct in the case that all of the older kids go to the larger table and the younger kids all go to the smaller table.  You neglected to take into consideration who goes to which table.

> Once taking that into consideration you get $\binom{12}{7}\cdot 6!\cdot 4!$ which will be the correct answer.

Comment: Just as I suspected. I was not sure if this will effect the outcome. how should I solve this?

Comment: @segevp multiply the expression you got by the number of ways to split them into a group of kids for the larger table and a group of kids for the smaller table.  (*N.B. If the tables were intended to be the same size and you couldn't otherwise tell the tables apart, you'll have to be a bit more careful with how you go about it, maybe by sending the birthday boy to a table first and then choosing how to split the rest of the kids*).